# How can I create a desktop shortcut to windows mail in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-mail

When I right click on it from the apps list (whatever replaced the start menu), I don't get an option to open file location, or even pin it anywhere.

It doesn't seem to be in C:\Program Files\Windows Mail either.

I went to the task manager to see where the running process came from. It comes from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

I changed the owner of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ to myself so that I could access it. The only exe that I see in the folders won't run.

Even if I find the exe, will the folder C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16.4.4206.722_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
 change its name ever?

Comment: Please revert the ownership of that folder.  Changing the ownership of that folder CAN and WILL cause problems for some Modern UI applications.  You are not suppose to be able to place a desktop shortcut to Modern UI applications.

Comment: @Ramhound I thought it may be a bad idea to change that, but if I didn't, I figured I wouldn't be pushing the envelope enough. is the default trusted installer?

Comment: @techie007 to my understanding, based on that thread, you can only configure windows mail as the default mail client. You can then create a shortcut to start a new email, but not open the app in general - i.e. to your inbox, which i think would be how most apps would work

Comment: @Hoppe - You said you changed the ownership of the folder.  You can assign any mail application as the default mail program